# Accessing members of base list class with derived list class?

Tags: c#

I have the following code: **it is not complete yet** but i want to know how to access members in the class with a foreach statement as indicated by the comment in code.  I suspect the answer is simple and I'm just not seeing it.  Can anyone help me?

```
public class PassengerList : List<Passenger>
{
    public bool CheckRules()
    { 

    }

    private bool DaughtersNotWithFather()
    { 
        foreach (Passenger p in ???)// how do i access list members in this class with this foreach statment?
        { // do stuff }
    }
}
```

Comment: never inheritance from list, dictionaries etc. this is way to hell

Comment: @burning_LEGION Do you care to explain why?

Comment: @Maarten i supported project with a lot of list's descendents, firstly you can't get normal serialization of this class, secondly usually some derived method is not need and some must be prohibited, thirdly you will get inconsistencies classes: BaseList and DerivedList are inconsistencies, but their items are consistencies, you will be write code to interact

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instance of your class is a `List<Passanger>` (which is enumerable). So, just refer your class via `this` keyword

```
foreach (Passenger p in this)
```

Comment: Bah, you slightly beat me to it. Only one right answer here, so I'm going to delete mine.  +1

Comment: No worries--good answers on SO are more important that multiple answers that say the same thing. =)